# Kotlin: @JvmStatic method NoClassDefFoundError/ClassNotFoundException during unit test

Tags: java, kotlin

This is the class that I'm trying to call from my unit test

```
package bj.discogsbrowser.artistreleases

class ArtistResultFactory {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun buildArtistResult(members: Int): ArtistResult {
            val artistResult = ArtistResult()
            artistResult.nameVariations = listOf("ye")
            artistResult.dataQuality = "really good quality, we have the best qualities"
            return artistResult
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the test looks like:

```
@Test
fun setArtistNoMembers_displaysNoMembers() {
    controller.setArtist(ArtistResultFactory.buildArtistResult(0))
    ...
    assertEquals(copyOfModels.size, 8)
}
```

Same test in Java (which also fails):

```
@Test
public void setArtistNoMembers_displaysNoMembers()
{
    controller.setArtist(ArtistResultFactory.buildArtistResult(0));
    ...
    assertEquals(copyOfModels.size(), 8);
}
```

In both Kotlin and Java I get the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bj/discogsbrowser/artistreleases/ArtistResultFactory

    at bj.discogsbrowser.artist.ArtistControllerTest.setArtistNoMembers_displaysNoMembers(ArtistControllerTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:488)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:209)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bj.discogsbrowser.artistreleases.ArtistResultFactory
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.getByteCode(SandboxClassLoader.java:161)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:101)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 32 more
```

I feel it may have something to do with my `sourceSets` as when I remove those lines then the code won't compile.

```
sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
        }
    }
```

`ArtistResultFactory` is located in `/src/testShared/`. When it was a Java class, the tests ran fine.

My app `build.gradle` includes

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it an "object" instead of "class" in order to access it singleton style in Kotlin.

If you do make it an object (which is the right thing to do with things like a Factory which are typically singletons), then in Java you will I believe have to do a .getINSTANCE() before you can access the method (not sure if you can make it static or not) as I don't believe companion objects are allowed on objects in Kotlin (I might be mistaken on that though).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about objects. This is currently a bug with the Canary build of Android Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079918/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-kotlin-tests-or-java-tests-referring-to-kotlin-clas
Going to vote to close this as it's a duplicate