# Android w/ Kotlin pure-java-Junit NoClassDefFoundError workaround not working

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

[Repository that reliably reproduces the error: explodes/bug-kotlin-junit](https://github.com/explodes/bug-kotlin-junit)

My Android app consists of an application module and 4 library modules.

My tests are written in pure Java. Tests that do not touch Kotlin code run just fine, but when I run tests that use (`MyKotlinObj::methodRef`) or inits a class (`new MyKotlinObj()`), my test will fail with the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/explod/api/UserCreated

    at com.explod.api.Bug.initUserCreated_shouldNotTriggerNoClassDefFoundError(Bug.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.explod.api.UserCreated
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
```

Using:

- Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2
- Build tools 26.0.0-rc2
- Kotlin Version 1.1.2-4
- Android-Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha2
- Gradle gradle-4.0-milestone-1
- Target SDK 25
- Min SDK 19

The workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085898/noclassdeffounderror-on-kotlin-class-in-junit-test-at-runtime) does not work for me:

```
android {
    task copyTestClasses(type: Copy) {
        from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debugUnitTest"
        into "build/intermediates/classes/debug"
    }
```

It looks like the [Android Studio team possibly has a solution](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38454212) but I am hoping for a workaround that works. Is my issue different? There is no Kotlin code in my tests.

Comment: Did you add a task before launch for `copyTestClasses`?

Comment: I did add it to my run configuration for the module in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the destination copy directory for the workaround was incorrect.

I had been using:

```
task copyTestClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebugUnitTest"
    into "build/intermediates/classes/devDebug"
}

task copySdkClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebug"
    into "build/intermediates/classes/dev/debug"
}
```

But the following works for me:

```
task copyTestClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebugUnitTest"
    into "build/intermediates/classes/dev/debug"
}

task copySdkClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebug"
    into "build/intermediates/classes/dev/debug"
}
```

On clean builds, the SDK classes are not available. I also needed to add `:api:assembleDevDebug` to the run configuration to make it work from clean builds.