# Kotlin Unit Test Not Finding Module Dependency Interface

Tags: android, gradle, mockito, kotlin

I have an `app` module and a `domain` module. In my `domain` module I have an interface called `Repository`. In my `app` module I use `dagger` to inject an implementation for this into my class and this works fine.

When I then go to test it using a kotlin unit test, at runtime I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I have also tried to include the `domain` module in my `app` modules dependencies like so but that also did not work:

```
testImplementation project(':domain')
```

Here are my current test dependencies and also how I'm including the module

```
implementation project(':domain')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0'
```

In my unit test I'm using it like this which could be the issue:

```
@Mock lateinit var mockRepo : Repository
```

Comment: Should you use `api project(':domain')` and not `implementation project(':domain')`?

Comment: I don't think so because there are no dependencies relying on my `app` module and it's only used internally? Unless I am understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: `com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0` includes `mockito-core` as a dependency? should that be `testApi com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0` - if `testApi` exists - As you're using `@Mock` annotation through the `com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0` library.

Comment: Tried changing that to `testApi` but no luck. Also tried `api project(':domain')` but that also didn't work.

Comment: To rule out dependencies I'd use `testCompile` (although 3.0+ deprecated should work fine) instead of `testImplementation`

Comment: Just used `testCompile` on `mockito-kotlin` and same issue.

Comment: Just had a thought, are you using `final` classes (default in kotlin unless you use `open` keyword) if so you need another test dependency  - `org.mockito:mockito-inline:x.xx.xx` -> x's should be the same version of `mockito-core` used in `com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0`

Comment: Good catch and I have fallen for that issue before. My `Repository` class is final. I added the `inline` dependency but still occurring even after clean. Using both `testImplementation` and `testApi`. Also changed `Repository` to open just to see but still `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Don't know off top my head - had a look around, this post may help ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079918/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-kotlin-tests-or-java-tests-referring-to-kotlin-clas

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks. your link to that question  led me on to the solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `@Mark Keen`, I was able to find a [reported bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17951) on the Jetbrains site.

This contained a solution from a user called `@Calin`. Adding the following to the projects's `build.gradle` file and triggering a gradle sync does the trick.

```
subprojects { subProject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if (subProject.plugins.hasPlugin("kotlin") && subProject.plugins.hasPlugin("java-library")) {
            subProject.kotlin.copyClassesToJavaOutput = true
            subProject.jar.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
        }
    }
}
```